# uploaded file from iPhone / iPad not rotating correctly despite image rotation script

Tags: php, image, upload, rotation, orientation

I have a script that uploads a file. I added a function that *should* rotate the image for photos uploaded from an iPhone or iPad ..because depending on how they are taken they could be shown sideways or upside down. I think I got the code correct but for some reason when performing the upload, it's still not rotated at all. What am I doing wrong?

```
    $uploadedFileName = $this->relative_path . $base_dir . $file_name;
    $is_upload = @copy($file_details['tmp_name'], $uploadedFileName);
    $exif = exif_read_data($uploadedFileName);
    $orientation = $exif['COMPUTED']['Orientation'];


    if (isset($orientation)) {

       switch ($orientation) {
          case 3:
             $image_p = imagerotate($uploadedFileName, 180, 0);
             break;
          case 6:
             $image_p = imagerotate($uploadedFileName, -90, 0);
             break;
          case 8:
             $image_p = imagerotate($uploadedFileName, 90, 0);
             break;
       }
       // Output
       imagejpeg($image_p, $uploadedFileName, 100);
    }
```

Comment: Where is defined `$image_p` variable?

Comment: You are right, I just updated the code. The upload works, however the image is still not rotated. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? :(

Comment: Check `$exif['COMPUTED']` array. What does it contain? What is $orientation value?

Answer (score 0):

The orientation is directly stored in the exif data. So your code should look like this:

```
$exif = exif_read_data($uploadedFileName);
$orientation = $exif['Orientation'];
switch ($orientation) {
   case 3:
      $image_p = imagerotate($uploadedFileName, 180, 0);
      break;
   case 6:
      $image_p = imagerotate($uploadedFileName, -90, 0);
      break;
   case 8:
      $image_p = imagerotate($uploadedFileName, 90, 0);
      break;
}
imagejpeg($image_p, $uploadedFileName, 100);
```